# Is there an easy way to download all plugins from the repo?

Tags: plugins

I want to do some Scans and Stats and would like to download every plugin in the WP Plugin Directory.

Is there an easier way to do this, other then clicking the download button 27k times?

What would be my best option for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subversion to access the plugin .svn library, then get the complete repository.

See: http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/ for more information

Answer (score 2):

SVN checkout is possible, but not usually recommended option (because SVN and 27k plugins).

Unofficial, but more popular option is [WordPress Plugin Directory Slurper](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Plugin-Directory-Slurper) script, which can download/update zip archive distributions of plugins.